# Why is my shared-host webserver caching my PHP script's file access?

Tags: php, caching, server

My PHP script, running on my shared-host website server, writes a text file on the server to save data between invocations of itself. **The problem** is that reading the text file seems to show a version from the recent past; the latest version of the file isn't there. It's as though the server were caching my script's file access.

**In more detail:** the script has two modes, write and read, depending on (*not germane*).

In the **write mode**, the script contains an HTML form into which the user enters data. The Submit button reloads the same script with the user's data coded in the URL as GET variables. The script appends the data to a file on the server. The code is:

```
    $dfile = fopen("datfile.txt","a");
    fwrite($dfile, $_GET['myname']."\n");
    fclose($dfile);
```

In the **read mode**, the script reads and displays the data file:

```
    $dfile = fopen("datfile.txt","r");
    if($dfile) while(!feof($dfile))
        echo fgets($dfile)."<br>";
    fclose($dfile);
```

**The problem** is that what is seen by the reader is not necessarily the writer's most current version. It's often a version from the recent past, as though the server were caching the script's file reads. I use FTP to make sure what the file really contains.

I've tried several ways to clear caches, with no effect. Many PHP versions, from 4.x to 7.3.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following site: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Scroll way down and it says:

"Note that this function affects only file metadata. However, all the PHP file system functions do their own caching of actual file contents as well. You can use the "realpath_cache_size = 0" directive in PHP.ini to disable the content caching if you like. The default content caching timeout is 120 seconds."